# Android - Show lock screen when application resumes in android

Tags: android

I need to show a lock screen when application comes from background and also after a time duration. I have searched a lot. But not found any useful solution. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to show the default lock screen ?

Comment: and the application comes from background meant?

Comment: @gursahib.singh.sahni Not default lock screen. Lock screen from my application. Background means when application is exit using back button or using home button

Comment: I suppose by "lockscreen" you mean something like a login for your app. Have a look at the `OnResume` and `OnPause` events in your `Activity`.

Comment: @germi For example if user pressed home button. Then he relaunched application. At that time i want to show an activity to enter user pin. If the pin is correct i have to show the activity from where user pressed home button

Comment: @user1767260 As I said: That's what `OnResume` is for. Have a look at the [Acitivity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html).

Comment: @germi but my application contains lot of activities.So I have to put in each activity. Any other solution?

Comment: You could have one activity in which you implement your desired behavior and have the other activities inherit from that one. That way you'd only have to implement it once. I did something similar in one of my apps.

Comment: @germi ok i will try and let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your added information in the comments, I'd suggest you have one base activity that implements your desired behavior and have your other activities inherit from that one.

It could look somewhat like this:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        // check if you want to display your login
    }
}
```

If you want to show your login after a set amount of time of inactivity, you could implement that in `BaseActivity`, too:

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction(){
    // reset your timer...
    super.onUserInteraction();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `KeyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent()` to get the user to unlock their device using the device PIN/password.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html#createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)